# How to hide Tablix in SSRS?

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I am facing problem in SSRS. Actually, I do have 3 Tablix in same report and want to hide 2 tablix based on Parameter value selected. I created parameter called Report and it having 3 values All, Emp with Service Hrs, Emp without Services hrs. Now what I am looking for if I select All then 2 tablix that belong to With Service Hrs and Without Service hrs should hide. similarlly for remaining 2 parameter as well.

I knew it is possible if you having 2 Tablix using IIf() but no idea on 3. If anyone knows then please give me ur feedback. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

There should be a ["Hidden" property](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159830%28SQL.100%29.aspx) that will take an IIF expressions.

Or [this link may be better](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677385%28SQL.100%29.aspx) which describes the assorted property pages for the Tablix